# convert getline() string of numbers to an array or ints

Tags: c++

I have a text file written as:

```
1 2 3
7 8 9
13 14 15
```

The goal is to make each column an array of integers, such that `x=[1,7,13]` , `y=[2,8,14]`, `z=[3,9,15]`.

Here is what I have so far...

I open the text file and read in the contents as a string:

```
string fileText;
int n;
int result[];
    //file open
        ifstream input ("input.txt");

    //file read
        if(input.is_open())
        {

            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) //n=3 in this case
            {
                 getline(input, fileText);
                 result = strtok(fileText," "); // parse each line by blank space " ".
                  //i get various errors here depending on what I try: such as "must be lvalue" 
                  //or a problem converting string to char.

                 x[i] = result[0];
                 y[i] = result[1];
                 z[i] = result[2];
            }

 }
```

So my problem is converting a line of text as numbers separated by a space into an array of integers.

This is pretty simple in a high-level language like PHP, but in C++ it gets more complicated with data types and mem allocation.. etc.  Plus I'm a novice!

Thanks

~

How would I do this without the vector?

If say I had:
int x*, y*, z*;

then allocate memory for each variable pointer:

```
    x = (int*) malloc (n*sizeof(int)); // where n is the number of lines in the text doc.
    y = (int*) malloc (n*sizeof(int));
    z = (int*) malloc (n*sizeof(int));
```

Now I want to put each column into each x,y,z integer array.

Can I do something like:

...

```
std::string line;
int i;
for (int k=0; k<n; k++) 
{
        while (std::getline (input, line))
        {
        std::stringstream parse(line);

        parse >> i;
        x[k] = i;
        parse >> i;
        y[k] = i;
        parse >> i;
        z[k] = i;

        }


    }
```

now x = [1,7,13] and so on.

Is there a way to do this without using the push_back() method?
I just want to read in the integers into each array.

use getNextInt() or something?

Comment: Are you familiar with e.g. `input >> x[i];`?

Comment: You don't want to mix C++ strings (`getline`) with C-style strings (`strtok`). Pick one or the other and stick with it.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on C++ IO: http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: This actually worked, after fixing some pointer issues.

Answer (score 4):

If your file is that simple, you can simply do the following:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
 ifstream input("input.txt");
 for(int x, y, z; input >> x >> y >> z;)
     v.push_back(std::vector<int>{x, y, z});
```

Or with `std::tuple`:

```
 std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> v;
 ifstream input("input.txt");
 for(int x, y, z; input >> x >> y >> z;)
     v.emplace_back(x, y, z);
```

This requires no conversions at all and will fail as soon as the stream fails. Both require, C++11 support, so if you need a C++03 solution, let me know.

If you want to stick with plain, old arrays:

```
 ifstream input("input.txt");
 for(int i = 0; input >> x[i] >> y[i] >> z[i]; ++i)
     ;
```

Answer (score 4):

creating a stringstream with the string returned from getline will probably be the most "C++" way to do what you are trying to do.

```
std::vector<int> x, y, z;
ifstream input ("input.txt");
if(input.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    int i;
    while (std::getline (input, line))
    {
        std::stringstream parse(line);
        // assuming 3 just like you had
        parse >> i;
        x.push_back (i);
        parse >> i;
        y.push_back (i);
        parse >> i;
        z.push_back (i);
    }
}
```

The conditional check isn't necessary, but I left it as you had it originally.

Comment: Note that stringstreams will work with mixed data types on a single line and also allows you to easily specify a delimiter.